# undefined method 'size' for Stack in Ruby

Tags: ruby, data-structures

I am trying to make a min stack function, but I think I don't understand something with the size of the loop, this is my code:

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :value, :next_node

  def initialize(value, next_node = nil)
    @value = value
    @next_node = next_node
  end
end
class LinkedList
  def initialize
    @head = nil
    @tail = nil
  end
  def add(number)
    new_node = Node.new(number)
    if @head.nil?
      @head = new_node
      @tail = new_node
    else
      @tail.next_node = new_node
      @tail = new_node
    end
  end
  def add_at(index, number)
    new_node = Node.new(number)
    if @head.nil?
      @head = new_node
      @tail = new_node
    else
      current = @head
      if index.zero?
        new_node.next_node = @head
        @head = new_node
        puts @head
      else
        (index - 1).times do
          current = current.next_node
        end 
        new_node.next_node = current.next_node
        current.next_node = new_node
        puts new_node
      end
    end
  end
  def get(index)
    current = @head
    index.times do
      current = current.next_node
    end
    current.value
  end
  def remove(index)
    if @head.nil?
      puts 'The list is already empty ^^'
    else
      if index.zero?
        @head = @head.next_node
        puts @head
      else
        current_at = @head
        (index - 1).times do
          current_at = current_at.next_node
        end
        tmp = current_at.next_node
        current_at.next_node = tmp.next_node
        puts tmp
      end
    end
  end
  def get_head
    @head
  end
end
class Stack
  def initialize
    @stack = LinkedList.new
  end
  def push(value)
    @stack.add_at(0, value)
  end
  def pop
    raise 'Stack is already empty' unless @stack
    temporal = @stack.get(0)
    @stack.remove(0)
    #temporal
  end

  def min
    current = @head
    (@stack.size).times do
      if current.next_node < current
        current = current.next_node
      end
    end
    current.value
  end

  def get_head
    @stack.get_head
  end
  def get_stack
    @stack
  end
end

stack = Stack.new
stack.push(3)
stack.push(5)
puts stack.min
# => 3

stack.pop
stack.push(7)
puts stack.min
# => 3

stack.push(2)
puts stack.min
# => 2

stack.pop
puts stack.min
# => 3
```

of course, this throws:

```
#<Node:0x0000560189f7b490>
undefined method `size' for #<LinkedList:0x0000560189f7b4e0>
(repl):90:in `min'
(repl):109:in `<main>'
```

this compiling with https://repl.it

ruby 2.5.5p157 (2019-03-15 revision 67260) [x86_64-linux]

The point of this is to create a Stack that contains a min method that returns the minimum number in the Stack.

I am trying as you see to create the min function with a Do Loop, but it's not working, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> what I am doing wrong?

You are calling `size` on `@stack`. However, `@stack` is a `LinkedList`, which doesn't have a `size` method.

Comment: :v how can I define size or length? or my way of thinking is wrong?